# Remote Desktop / Anydesk using host machine name rather than the Remote Machine name for Print Commands

Tags: windows, server, printing, remote-desktop, windows-server

I am using my system (Windows 10) to connect to a Windows Server 2019 via Anydesk or Microsoft Remote Desktop. We are using a pharmacy software to print some labels which is configured to use different set of printers based on the machine name. When a print command is being given in the pharmacy software installed on Windows Server (via a remote session), the host name being used in my system's name (Windows 10) and not the Windows Server one. This causes the printer configuration to not be respected as the machine name is different.

I have tried setting my Anydesk Profile Name to be the Windows Server's Machine but that does not work. If I change my Windows 10 Machine name to be the same one as the Windows Server machine name and then issue the command from the Windows Server, the label prints fine.

This solution is not practical as we have different printers configured to work with different Windows Server machines so each time a different printer needs to be used, the Windows 10 machine's system name will need to be updated and restarted.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it by using a VNC Server + Client instead of Remote Desktop or Anydesk. [RealVNC](https://realvnc.com) was the VNC that was used.